# How to tell another view controller what song to play that is listed on a table view?

Tags: swift

In my PlayerViewController, I am trying to play a song that is selected from my Table view. Also this first line of code is in another view controller. What would be a better way to write the player.playStream line?

EDIT: PlayerViewController

```
@IBOutlet weak var playPauseButton: UIButton!
var player: Player!
var song: [Song] = []
let indexPath = IndexPath()
var MusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     player = Player()
    setSession()
    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    becomeFirstResponder()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("handleInterruption")), name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification, object: nil)




    player.playStream(fileUrl: "http://127.0.0.1/musicfiles" + song[indexPath.row].getName())
    changePlayButton()
}
```

Song.swift:

```
class Song {

var id = Int()
var name = String()
var year = Int()
var numLikes = Int()
var numPlays = Int()

init?(id:String, name:String, year:String, numlikes:String, numplays:String) {
    self.id = Int(id)!
    self.name = name
    self.year = Int(year)!
    self.numLikes = Int(numLikes)
    self.numPlays = Int(numplays)!
}

func getId() -> Int {
    return id
}

func getName() -> String {
    return name
}

func getYear() -> Int {
    return year
}

func getNumLikes() -> Int {
    return numLikes
}

func getNumPlays() -> Int {
    return numPlays
}
}
```

Comment: `Song` is the class name. You need to reference your array.

Comment: Yes, now I'm getting a crash: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600001ee2dc0> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46

Comment: Can you post the code for `PlayerViewController`

Comment: You need to pass the `Song` value from your `tableView`.

Comment: You mean, var song: [Song] = []   ?